# Cannot resolve symbol "api" in "com.google.api"

Tags: android, api, google-drive-api, image-uploading, android-studio-import

I am using Android Studio 1.3 in which I want to build an app which upload images to Google Drive. I am following [Google Drive Android Quickstart](https://github.com/googledrive/android-quickstart) to build my app, but when I use the code from this project then  [this error appears:](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vo1RV.png)

I also imported the google-play-services.jar file into my project but this error still appearing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are likely missing

```
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-drive:8.4.0'
```

from your gradle dependencies

Comment: How can I compile this missing dependencies in gradle? thanks in advance